# How to run maven test with Spark sumbit?

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, testing, automated-tests

I have a Spark application that does Data transformation jobs with some Scalatest cases, which I could run locally. Is it possible to use Spark summit to run those tests as part of a pipeline? I only see --class as Spark summit argument. The idea is to run those tests first, if they all passed, the application will run. Or if this is not the way, how would you achieve this? Many thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why not have a normal CI system that builds and tests code that is to be run in production?

Comment: @ErnestKiwele Thanks for your reply. For example if I change the logic of one column later, I want to run this sample dataset to make sure the rest of the cols still produce the same results. How do you handle this situation?